# Formato do Date no select

Tags: java, jsf, java-ee, jsf-2.2

Tenho esse método:

```
    public List<LoteEnvEntity> findallByDate(java.util.Date dataDe, java.util.Date dataAte) {
    String strQuery = "SELECT L FROM LoteEnvEntity as L WHERE 1=1";
    //SimpleDateFormat simpledate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-dd-MM");
    Query query = getEntityManager().createQuery(strQuery);     
    if (dataDe != null)
    {
        strQuery += " and L.dateEnvio >= :dataDe";// + simpledate.format(dataDe);
        query.setParameter(":dataDe", dataDe);
    }

    if (dataAte != null)
    {
        strQuery += " and L.dateEnvio <= :dataAte"; //+ simpledate.format(dataAte);
        query.setParameter(":dataAte", dataAte);
    }           

    return (List<LoteEnvEntity>) query.getResultList();     
}
```

Só que no console aparece erro no *convert* da data, pois a data vem no seguinte formato: "Wed Nov 05 00:00:00 BRST 2014". E preciso usar ele no select da *Entity*, como podem ver já tentei usar o `SimpleDateFormat`.

Answer (score 1):

Utilize o seguinte código:

```
query.setParameter("dataDe", dataDe, TemporalType.DATE);
```

Comment: Caso sua resposta de fato solucione o problema, se poss[ivel, explique-a melhor.